How to filter foreign key for using ModelMultipleChoiceFilter in DRF?
I'm getting trouble with using ModelMultipleChoiceFilter in DRF.
First, I have three models.
# JUST STRUCTURE
class A -> fields : [user:User]
class B -> fields : [a:A(related_name="b"), c:C]
class C -> fields : [name:string]

And I want to filter with C's names (multiple choice) in class A.
So... in views.py,
class ShortFormListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   queryset = A.objects.all()
   filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
   filterset_class = AFilterSet

and in filters.py,
class AFilterSet(FilterSet):
    aa = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        field_name='b__c__name',
        to_field_name='name',
        lookup_expr='in',
        queryset=C.objects.all(),
        widget=CSVWidget,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ShortForm
        fields = ['aa']

It worked but I think it is not efficient way.
Is there any solutions?
